# How do I hide the titlebar and lock the position on an exe (unmanaged code) that I have moved inside a panel in a c# form?

Tags: .net, user32

I have to "embed" an .exe within a panel in a .net windows form.
I am doing this using user32.dll SetParent to set the launched app's parent to the forms Panel handle.

Once this is done, I would like to

1. Hide the title bar of the .exe
2. lock the exe into the panel (maximized) so it cannot be moved or closed.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the titlebar from a window using the GetWindowLong and [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591(VS.85).aspx)(GWL_ STYLE) function to remove the WS_CAPTION style bit.